# KeyError Why is dictionary empty?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanna make a dictionary that has `name`'s key & data. In views.py I wrote

```
data_dict ={}
def try_to_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)
    except:
        return arg

def main():
    book4 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet4 = book4.sheet_by_index(0)

    data_dict_origin = OrderedDict()
    tag_list = sheet4.row_values(0)[1:]
    for row_index in range(1, sheet4.nrows):
        row = sheet4.row_values(row_index)[1:]
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        data_dict_origin[row_index] = dict(zip(tag_list, row))

        print(data_dict_origin)

        for value in data_dict_origin.values():
            if value['name'] in data_dict_origin:
                data_dict[value['name']].update(value)
            else:
                data_dict[value['name']] = value

    print(data_dict)

main()
```

`print(data_dict_origin)` gives:

```
OrderedDict([(1, {'user_id': '100', 'group': 'A', 'name': 'Tom', 'dormitory': 'C'})])
```

So, I really cannot understand why this error happens.
I tried other things like:

```
for value in data_dict.values():
            if value['name'] in data_dict:
                data_dict[value['name']].update(value)
            else:
                data_dict[value['name']] = value
```

`{}` was shown.
How should I fix this?

Comment: But you use `data_dict[value['name']].update(value)`? Shouldn't you always write `data_dict[value['name']] = value`?

Comment: Your `data_dict_origin` keys are integers, so `value['name'] in data_dict_origin` is never going to be true. Did you mean to test `value['name'] in data_dict` instead?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: They are trying to collate the dictionaries by name, so no.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried `if value['name'] in data_dict:` ,but same error happens.How should I fix this?If u know something,could u write ur codes in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Simple is better than complex.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(dict)


def try_to_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)
    except:
        return arg


def main():
    book4 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet4 = book4.sheet_by_index(0)

    tag_list = sheet4.row_values(0)[1:]
    for row_index in range(1, sheet4.nrows):
        row = sheet4.row_values(row_index)[1:]
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        value = dict(zip(tag_list, row))

        print(value)
        if value.get('name', ''):
            data_dict[value['name']].update(value)


    print(data_dict)


main()
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I got same error in this part `data_dict[value['name']].update(value)` how should I fix this?

Comment: Did you replaced `data_dict ={}` with `data_dict = defaultdict(dict)` ? If answer is **yes** I assume, that KeyError raised because `name` not in `value`

Comment: Yes,I replaced  data_dict ={} with data_dict = defaultdict(dict) .So should I write `closing_rate_dict ={}
closing_rate_dict =defaultdict(dict)
def try_to_int(arg):・・・` ?I wrote so and run ,but same error happens.

Comment: I don't think so. Looks like your error appears because your input data don't have 'name' key on some of your rows.

Comment: Try edited code and compare `data_dict` with `./data/excel1.xlsx`. If any row is missing - the problem located in it